# Finding a check in Chrome

Tags: debugging, patching

Chrome doesn't allow switching on extensions which are not from the Chrome store.
[image]
There is no this limitation in Chromium. So it is only in Chrome.
It checks `verified_contents.json` (in which content hashes) and existence of the `update_url` parameter in the manifest.
How to find this check and fix this? I am interested in solving this with debugging. Please help.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532015 & https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/external_extensions/ ... but I don't quite see what this has to do with reverse engineering, given it's a setting.

Comment: @0xC0000022L It works only for the store extensions. I am interested in solving this with reverse engineering, that is why I ask here.